# Elixir gulp tdd to run specific test

Tags: gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

In order to run tests on Laravel, the documentation only mention:

```
mix.phpUnit();
```

But this end up running all my tests every time I save a file. 
Is there a way to run specific test case or file ? something like:

```
mix.phpUnit('DefaultControllerTest');
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:
in gulpfile.js I added:

```
mix.phpUnit(null, {group: 'Tour'});
```

Then in my tests I added a meta group

```
/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 * @group Tour
 */
public function testExample()
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

This runs only tests with the meta @group Tour